# Unable to connect with local Docker machine from Visual Studio Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I installed "Docker(0.0.27)" extension in Visual Studio Code(running locally on laptop) to build docker images without leaving the IDE. But observed following issue when issued "docker version" command from VS code terminal window..

I even set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable to connect with docker machine running on my local machine using following command. But it did't help. Has anyone faced this issue while working with VS code ?

**SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://DockerMachineIP:2376**

**Error**

Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the
default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Comment: @gama11, I can see that you edited this post 21 hours ago. I've fixed the issue but am unable to post the answer. Can you help me here?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to post the answer" exactly?

Comment: @gama11, getting following message while trying to post the answer - "We are no longer accepting answer from this account" :(

Comment: Hm, interesting, it looks like there's an automated "answer ban": https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans - 'The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out"' :/

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "Positive contribution" to the site ?

Comment: I don't know more than what's in that article I linked either, I'm just quoting from there. :)